# Checking a date between two months sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to check if the date I have is (for example) between 10th of march and 20th of april and it should work on any year.
I'm really new to sql server, I found really good discussions on comparing dates, but they all include years and I don't want to hard-code the year. 
How this should be done in a neat way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract parts of the date `DAY`, `MONTH` and `YEAR` respectively. For example

```
Select MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Will give you the Month Number for the current date.

If you want to check if a month is between certain values before doing an insert:

```
If Exists (Select 'x' Where Month(GETDATE()) Between 3 and 4 --March to April
Begin
  --Do work here
End
```

If you want to get all values from a table where the CreatedDate is between two values:

```
Select *
From MyTable
Where MONTH(CreatedDate) Between 3 and 4 -- March to April
```

Finally, to check if CreatedDate is between two specific dates in a year (but any year), you could do the below.

```
Select *
From MyTable
Where CreatedDate Between Convert(Varchar, YEAR(CreatedDate)) + '-03-12' 
        and Convert(Varchar, YEAR(CreatedDate)) + '-03-15'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a shorter way, but you could do

```
SELECT  *
FROM your table
--this will transform your date in a varchar with 2 digits for month and 2 digits for day
WHERE  RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(CAST (MONTH(<yourdatefield>) as varchar(2))), 2) + 
       RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(cast(DAY(<yourdatefield>) as varchar(2))), 2)

BETWEEN '0310' and '0410'
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26c4e/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use following approach which generates `StartDateTime` - `StopDateTime` ranges for every year from `Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate` column (I've used [AdventureWorks sample database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587): SQL2008+). This approach is SARG-able and with an index on `OrderDate` column the execution plan for the last SELECT statement will include an `Index Seek`:

```
CREATE INDEX IN_SalesOrderHeader_OrderDate
ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader(OrderDate);
GO

DECLARE @StartDay TINYINT, 
    @StartMonth TINYINT,
    @StopDay TINYINT, 
    @StopMonth TINYINT;

SELECT @StartDay = 10,
    @StartMonth = 3,
    @StopDay = 20,
    @StopMonth = 4;

DECLARE @FirstYear SMALLINT, @LastYear SMALLINT;
SELECT  TOP(1) @FirstYear = YEAR(h.OrderDate)
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h    
WHERE   h.OrderDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY h.OrderDate ASC;   

SELECT  TOP(1) @LastYear = YEAR(h.OrderDate)
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h    
WHERE   h.OrderDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY h.OrderDate DESC;  

WITH N10(Num) 
AS 
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10  
), N100(Num)
AS
(
    SELECT  (a.Num - 1)*10 + b.Num
    FROM    N10 a CROSS JOIN N10 b
)
SELECT  COUNT(z.SalesOrderID) AS SalesOrderCount
FROM 
(
    SELECT  x.CurrentYear, 
        StartDateTime   = DATEADD(DAY, @StartDay-1, DATEADD(MONTH, @StartMonth-1, DATEADD(YEAR, x.CurrentYear - 1900, 0))),
        StopDateTime    = DATEADD(DAY, @StopDay/*-1*/, DATEADD(MONTH, @StopMonth-1, DATEADD(YEAR, x.CurrentYear - 1900, 0)))
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  @FirstYear + n.Num - 1 AS CurrentYear
        FROM    N100 n
        WHERE   n.Num <= (@LastYear - @FirstYear + 1)
    ) x
) y
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT  h.SalesOrderID
    FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
    WHERE   h.OrderDate >= y.StartDateTime
    AND     h.OrderDate < y.StopDateTime
) z
```

The execution plan:

[image]

Note: this solution assumes that `Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate` column has maximum 100 years.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following link for EXTRACT function which helps you get only the month from a date:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp

Comment: mysql functions don't help much for sql server !